# React Native : Async and Await is a reserved word error inside onPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I'm facing a weird problem. In my react native app I have a `Googlebutton` which trigger `onPress` and it will check the condition within it, but the problem is I have `await` reserved word which returns me an error says `Unexpected reserved word await` I'm trying to apply `Pincode`

**Main Code**

```
 import PINCode, {hasUserSetPinCode,resetPinCodeInternalStates,deleteUserPinCode,
 } from "@haskkor/react-native-pincode";

<GoogleSigninButton
   style={{ width: 252, height: 58 }}
   size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
   color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
   onPress={() => {

   const hasPin = await hasUserSetPinCode();
   if (fingerprint === true) {
       googleLogin();
   }

   else if (hasPin) {
       console.log("Alert pinnn should pop up");
   }

   else {
      console.log("Alert should pop up");
      setModalVisible(true);
    }
   }
 }
/>
```

This is what I've tried I've put  **async (hasUserSetPinCode)** before the await but it returns no value in my console, it seems it's not working

**putting an async**

```
import PINCode, {hasUserSetPinCode,resetPinCodeInternalStates,deleteUserPinCode,
}from "@haskkor/react-native-pincode";

<GoogleSigninButton
     style={{ width: 252, height: 58 }}
     size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
     color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
     onPress={async() => {
     /* ------------------ The async below Doesn't work ----------------------------------- */
     
     const hasPin = await hasUserSetPinCode();
        if (fingerprint === true) {
           googleLogin();
        }
        else if (hasPin) {
           console.log("Alert pinnn should pop up");
        }
        else {
           console.log("Alert should pop up");
           setModalVisible(true);
        }
     }
  
/>
```

[image]

Comment: By `onPress={() => {}`, it is essentially providing a callback function inside which you are trying to `await` something. You can simply make the callback function as `async` by  `onPress={async() => {}` and it would just work fine.

Comment: @nithinpp I've already tried that and I've posted code above but It didn't showed any value, no error nothings happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place `async` before the function in which it is used.

```js
import PINCode, {hasUserSetPinCode,resetPinCodeInternalStates,deleteUserPinCode,
 } from "@haskkor/react-native-pincode";

<GoogleSigninButton
   style={{ width: 252, height: 58 }}
   size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
   color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
   onPress={async () => {

   const hasPin = await hasUserSetPinCode();
   if (fingerprint === true) {
       googleLogin();
   }

   else if (hasPin) {
       console.log("Alert pinnn should pop up");
   }

   else {
      console.log("Alert should pop up");
      setModalVisible(true);
    }
   }
 }
/>
```

Comment: thanks for your response ,I tried your code but it returns me an error like this image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ytmg.png)  do you have idea?

Comment: I solve it after installing `react-native keychain`